# Can I return a component from another function instead main function in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, alert

I am trying to return `AwesomeAlerts` component which I have made using `react-native-awesome-alerts` to send alert if a user doesn't add a required field in react native. But It isn't working.

My code:

```
const handleSubmitPress = async () => {
    try {
      if (!userEmail) {
        alert("Please add username");
        return <AwesomeAlerts title="Error" message="Please add username" />; // not working
      } 
      if (!userPassword) {
        alert("Please add password");
        return;
      }
      setLoading(true);
      const user = await Auth.signIn(userEmail, userPassword);
      console.log("response:", user);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

And, If I use `AwesomeAlerts` in main function then it's working fine.

```
 return (
<TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.buttonStyle}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              onPress={handleSubmitPress}
            >
 {loading ? (
                <View style={styles.activityIndicator}>
                  <ActivityIndicator color={colors.BorderColor} size="large" />
                </View>
              ) : (
               <AwesomeAlerts title="Error" message="Please add username" /> // working find
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Can I return a componenet from another function like above? How can I use `react-native-awesome-alerts` inside `handleSubmitPress`?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react
here is the link.
Can you try to use the concept of inheritance. I think that may help you